# Full page/screen FLEXBOX layout

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I'm currently using the flexbox approach for a layout that I'm trying to achieve. I have read over the documentation and also have been playing around with it on a recent project. However I am struggling (I'm not sure if this common problem, or whether I don't have a decent solution for it). As the title states I'm trying to achieve a full page layout which contains 8 divs all equally proportioned to the screen (2 rows of 4 divs OR 4 columns of 2 divs).

I have done this to an extent, but the real problem is the images which are placed within the divs itself. If I use 'vh' and 'vw' unit's to size the images/divs, when the browser is resized they stay proportionate to the window but the images are really skewed and squished up.

If I don't state the vh/vw units and use % instead the images stay the correct size but the divs get smaller.

I'm trying to achieve a fullscreen layout with the 8 divs and images staying proportionate to the window all the time when resizing vertically or horizontally.

Here is my view file;
[image]

Here is my html;

```
<div id="section-two" class="section-wrapper">
    <div class="parent-container">
        <div class="child">
            <img class="feature-image" ng-src="/assets/01_RETAIL_DESIGN.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="child">
            <img class="feature-image" ng-src="/assets/02_BRANDING.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="child">
            <img class="feature-image" ng-src="/assets/03_STRATEGIC_INSIGHTS.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="child">
            <img class="feature-image" ng-src="/assets/04_COMMERCIAL_MASTERPLANNING.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="child">
            <img class="feature-image" ng-src="/assets/05_URBANREGENERATION.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="child">
            <img class="feature-image" ng-src="/assets/06_FOODANDBEVERAGE_DESIGN.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="child">
            <img class="feature-image" ng-src="/assets/07_TRANSPORT.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="child">
            <img class="feature-image" ng-src="/assets/08_SIGNAGEANDWAYFINDING.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my css;

```
.section-wrapper {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.parent-container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    font-size: 0;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 0; 
}
.child {
    -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 50%;
    width: calc(100% * (1/4));
    position: relative;
}
.feature-image {
    height: 50vh;
}
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be sizing the images at all. That's what the grid is for. I'd put an absolutely-positioned element inside each grid box (to keep your image styling separate) and set the images as backgrounds on those. Something like this:

.child {position: relative;}
.img-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
}

```
<div class="child">
    <div class="img-wrapper" ng-style="{'background-image': '/assets/blah.jpg'}" />
    </div>
</div>
```

You may need to use `$sce` and return the background style rule via a controller function for security reasons.

Comment: This method works. I was having problems with images prior to this, using ng-class works really well.

Answer (score -1):

I am new to code and do not know how to position your code with the method you are using, but if you want, try using either floats or inline-block to position you content. They have both worked very well for me and I think you will be successful with them. For a really good grid outline for a page go here: http://learn.shayhowe.com/html-css/positioning-content/ Good luck!

~Jacob

Comment: Im trying to use flexbox attributes to position my elements without floating